# Scripting Stored Procedure, Functions in Code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using manual database migration.

Currently, whenever there is any new stored procedure or a function I am creating a migration through the following approach:

```
Add-Migration CreatefnGenerateRequestCode
```

Now the class `CreatefnGenerateRequestCode` has been created by the framework.

I have two options (as far as I know) that either I can write inline `create procedure` SQL code or I can read the SQL script from the folder.

I don't like inline approach because as the procedure goes complicated I don't want to keep concatenating strings.

So what I have found is the approach through which I can load embedded resource with the dll.

Now, what I do is create a script file

I have a folder called `Scripts` that stores `fnGenerateRequestCode.sql` and now I have embedded this with the dll.

Now, with the help of this code I read it from the dll:

```
private string GetFileCode(string resourceName)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string result;

    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And my whole migration class looks like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    var resourceName = "CBA.RBS.CEDS.Data.Scripts.fnGenerateRequestCode.sql";
    var inlinecode = this.GetFileCode(resourceName);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inlinecode)) { }
    else
    {
        Sql(inlinecode);
    }
}

public override void Down()
{
    Sql("Drop function dbo.fnGenerateRequestCode");
}
```

But the problem with this approach that every time I have a script to execute, I will have to embed with the DLL that I don't know if it is really a good solution because the dll is going to be loaded into the memory and it will eventually can eat lots of memory space.

I have tried may other ways but I cannot read these script files when I execute `Update-Database`.

One way I tried is `Copy to Output Directory`, but I don't think I can read the same as I get below error:

> PM> Update-database Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL
>   statements being applied to the target database. Applying explicit
>   migrations: [201410230234306_CreateFullBackupProcedure]. Applying
>   explicit migration: 201410230234306_CreateFullBackupProcedure.
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'C:\Users\MalhAm\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\G787MA29.K3X\JL3MCKQY.NGR\8b8db792\7af63578_6beecf01\Scripts\spFullBackup.sql'.

Can someone please clarify two things:

1. When we embed resources with the dll, is it going to take space or not. If so then my approach is good?
2. How others are doing?

Comment: I have the same problem and I deside to use "Copy to Output Directory".